# getInitialAppLink from app_links return null from Play Store - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I am using [app_links](https://pub.dev/packages/app_links) for linking my App. If the app is already installed I am receiving the correct link from getInitialAppLink(). However if my app is not installed when I click on the link it opens play store(correct behaviour) but after I install the app from there getInitialAppLink() returns null.

**Intent filter in my AndroidManifest.xml
**

```
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host= myDomain
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />

            </intent-filter>
```

**Code to get link

```
AppLinks _appLinks;

Future<void> initDeepLinks() async {
 Uri appLink;


 _appLinks = AppLinks();

  _linkSubscription = _appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen((uri) {
    
      appLink = uri;

  });
 appLink = await _appLinks.getInitialAppLink();
}
```

Expected behaviour - Get the correct link after coming from play store instead of null